# React: "react-scripts start" cannot find module webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am getting this error when I am not even using webpack in this particular branch. I have never encountered this error in my **main** branch before. However, I wanted to learn webpack so I created a **webpack** branch of my project and install webpack in that branch(Assuming that I did correctly install webpack locally). Now when I switch back to my **main**, and tried to run "`npm start`". I am getting into this error.

```
> react-scripts start

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pzheng\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:22:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

When I tried to run "npm run build", this error appears instead:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/Chunk'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pzheng\my-app\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:17:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pzheng\my-app\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
```

Many SO posts suggesting downloading webpack, but I do not wish to use webpack for this branch, so many SO posts are not helpful.

**What I have tried:**
I checked my `package.json file`, there is no webpack dependency in my **main** branch. However, I do see webpack in my `package.lock.json` file when I search for the word `webpack`

**What I am using:**
I am using `create-react-app` library.

**What I need help with:**
I am trying to figure out the cause of this error and how to fix it. Does it have to do with me installing webpack in the other branch?

Comment: I usually just drop the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again, but certainly it isn't an answer to the "why" question.

Comment: @0xc14m1z i also tried that and it din not fix the problem

Comment: _when I am not even using webpack in this particular branch._ What do you exactly mean by "branch" here?

Comment: @hindmost I am refeering to the git branch. so I started off my project using `create-react-app`. It is like my personal project to practice react. Then I trying to learn webpack, so I created a seperarte branch where I installed webpack.

Comment: @aDev webpack comes shipped with `create-react-app`, you don't need to install it again. If you need to tweak it's configuration, then you should `eject` your app.

Comment: @0xc14m1z this is why I am suspecting that it may have to do with me install webpack in the other branch, but since they are in different branch, they should not affect each other. However, right now, i just wanted to run my app on local, which is blocked by this error

Comment: The branch doesn't matter if you have the application generated via CRA on both branches.

Comment: @0xc14m1z so what does it mean? are you saying that the webpack i installed on the other branch will affect main branch?

Comment: Perhaps in your case switching between branches affects module files (incl. webpack). Don't use the same directory for both branches. Just copy original project folder to other location and create a new branch there.

Comment: @hindmost should I remove the other branch from the directory then?

Comment: Yeah, and switch to the original branch

Comment: @hindmost the error seem to be fixed. However, I will definitely keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is weird but this is how I fixed it.

I think this error has to do with "react-script"

I was using `react-script@1.3`, as soon as I upgrade my react script to `2.1.3`, which is the latest version published 4 days ago, this error is fixed.

Answer (score 25):

I faced this when I was trying to use `react-scripts` in an existing react app that wasn't scaffolded using `create-react-app`. The problem was the package-lock file. Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` did the trick for me.

Comment: Don't forget remove "webpack" and "webpack-dev-server" dependencies from package.json.

Comment: Ashwin M you are a scholar and a gentleperson

Answer (score 0):

You are using CRA (Create React App) which is already using webpack (with it's own config file). CRA offers the option to 'eject', which will expose the webpack config file that you can then modify and play with. If you do choose to eject, do so on another branch (in case you decide to go back). Be aware that ejecting is non-reversible.

Hope this helps!